# Hibernate is not setting child foreign key when persisting with SpringData

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Hy!

I have tried every solution and read every stackoverflow post, but I can't find a solution to my problem. I am using Spring boot with SpringData, DB is Oracle 11.

I have a OneToMany relation in my parent

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column (name = "uuid", nullable = false)
private UUID uuid;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Children> children;
```

and in the child

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Parent parent;
```

the foreign keys are of type UUID, in DB raw(16)

When I try to save the Parent using

```
Parent entity = parentRepository.save(parent);
```

the result is that the foreign key in the child which ties it to the Parent is not set, it remains empty. I have added a lot of unnecessary annotations params hoping that something would fix it. I am starting to think that may be Hibernate does not like UUIDs?

Comment: pls provide the code how your object `parent` is created

Comment: and how the childs are added to the parent

Comment: @C.Weber jup, you are correct, posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation for hibernate I found out that I should manually set the children in my parent.

I rewrote my setter method in parent as follows. I tried it before once, but did something wrong then. This solution works fine. I also found another stackoverflow post, where this solution was mentioned.

```
  public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.children)) {
      this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    children.forEach(child -> {
      group.setParent(this);
      this.children.add(group);
    });
  }
```